# При выводе в цикле из бд в листобокс ничего не видно

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

вот вывод в цикле всех значений колонки:

```
<?php

$sql_s_core = "SELECT nameM FROM dbo.menu";
$result_core = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql_s_core);
while ($row_core = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result_core,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))

echo '<option value="'. $row_core['nameM'] . '" name="'. $row_core['nameM'] . '">';
    echo $row_core['nameM'];
echo '</option>';
?>
```

но в браузре оббабатывается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если открыть исходнк то там все есть:

```
element for:
<select id="m_elements">
<option>root element</option>

<option value="TEST1" name="TEST1"><option value="TEST2" name="TEST2"><option value="TEST3" name="TEST3"><option value="TEST5" name="TEST5"><option value="TEST4" name="TEST4"><option value="TEST7!" name="TEST7!"><option value="PUNKT!!!!" name="PUNKT!!!!"><option value="PARENT" name="PARENT"><option value="PARENT" name="PARENT"><option value="" name=""><option value="" name=""><option value="" name=""><option value="" name=""><option value="" name=""></option></option>
</select>
     <input type="submit">
```

Comment: Закрывающий тэг </option> неверно прописан. Они все в конце собрались.

Comment: echo '</option>'; есть же

Comment: Исходный код то посмотрите, там не валидно все.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$sql_s_core = "SELECT nameM FROM dbo.menu";
$result_core = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql_s_core);
while ($row_core = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result_core,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    echo '<option value="'. $row_core['nameM'] . '" name="'. $row_core['nameM'] . '">';
    echo $row_core['nameM'];
    echo '</option>';
}
```

Вы забыли скобки у while. Без скобок циклится только первая строка.